# C# return before await - without starting a new Task

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, async-await

This is for an `iOS` app written in `Xamarin`. All my application code runs in the main thread (i.e. the `UI thread`).

The UI code does something as follows:

```
public async void ButtonClicked()
{
    StartSpinner();
    var data = await UpdateData();
    StopSpinner();
    UpdateScreen(data);
}
```

The `UpdateData` function does something as follows:

```
public Task<Data> UpdateData()
{
   var data = await FetchFromServer();
   TriggerCacheUpdate();
   return data;
}
```

`TriggerCacheUpdate` ends up calling the following function defined below

```
public Task RefreshCache()
{
    var data = await FetchMoreDataFromServer();
    UpdateInternalDataStructures();
}
```

My question is how should `TriggerCacheUpdate` be written? The requirements are:

1. Can't be async, I don't want `UpdateData` and consequently
   `ButtonClicked` to wait for `RefreshCache` to complete before
   continuing.
2. `UpdateInternalDataStructures` needs to execute on the main (UI) thread, i.e. the thread that all the other code shown above executes on.

Here are a few alternatives I came up with:

```
public void TriggerCacheUpdate()
{
    RefreshCache();
}
```

The above works but generates a compiler warning. Moreover exception handling from `RefreshCache` doesn't work.

```
public void TriggerCacheUpdate()
{
    Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        await RefreshCache();
    });
}
```

The above violates requirement 2 as `UpdateInternalDataStructures` is not executed on the same thread as everything else.

A possible alternative that I believe works is:

```
private event EventHandler Done; 
public void TriggerCacheUpdate()
{
    this.task = RefreshCache();
    Done += async(sender, e) => await this.task;
}

Task RefreshCache() {
    var data = await FetchMoreDataFromServer();
    UpdateInternalDataStructures();
    if (Done != null) {
       Done(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Does the above work? I haven't ran into any problems thus far with my limited testing. Is there a better way to write `TriggerCacheUpdate`?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If the question is unclear, please add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without being able to test it but it looks like your trigger cache update method is fine, it's your RefreshCache that needs to change. Inside of RefreshCache you are not waiting in the UI thread for the result of "data" to return so set the ConfigureAwait to false.

```
public async Task RefreshCache()
{
    var data = await FetchMoreDataFromServer().ConfigureAwait(false);
    UpdateInternalDataStructures();
}
```

Comment: Why would I set ConfigureAwait(false)? I want UpdateInternalDataStructures() to be executed in the main thread. If I set ConfigureAwait(false), it may get executed in any thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is async. That means, that even if you await for a Task to complete, that your UI remains responsive. So even if you would await for the TriggerCacheUpdate to return, your UI would remain responsive.

However, if you are really certain that you are not interested in the result of TriggerCachUpdate, then you could start a Task without waiting for it:

```
public Task<Data> UpdateData()
{
    var data = await FetchFromServer();
    Task.Run( () => TriggerCacheUpdate());
    return data;
}
```

> Note: careful: you don't know when TriggerCachUpdate is finished, not even if it ended successfully or threw an exception. Also: check what happens if you start a new TriggerCacheUpdate task while the previous one is not finished yet.

For those who want to use Task.Factory.StartNew, see the discussion about it in MSDN:

[Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

Comment: I want to UI to update before TriggerCacheUpdate returns. So yes it will remain responsive but it will continue to show a spinner and never update. Task.Run( () => TriggerCacheUpdate()); will cause TriggerCacheUpdate to run in a separate thread not in the main thread.